# How would you remove an answer from a list in ConfirmIT?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long list scale/list setup named `list1` - it's often being used in our surveys.

However, we now have to remove an option from that list for a particular question (Answer code 125), but don't want to completely remove it from that scale/list as we still use it in our other questions.

How would I mask this particular answer option when people click on the drop down list?

I suppose a script code that involves hiding `list1_125`?

So what I'm trying to do in other words is to hide an answer's choice from a selected list.

Thank you.

Comment: I would be nice, if you could add some of the relevant code + html. Without it we could only guess what could help you.

Comment: ConfirmIT is a survey deploying platform: confirmit.com . You basically have some interface to work with that requires little to no coding knowledge, however the moment you want to add more features to it, it's when the coding begins.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a code mask on the question. If you have 200 answer options in list1 and you do not want answer option 125 to appear in Question 2 (as an example), I would add this code mask to Question 2:

nset('124').union(nnset('126','200'))

*nset displays the first answer option to the answer option specified

nnset displays the answer options between and including the answer options specified*

Answer (score 2):

Below is a better way to do the precode mask. This way, new answers will automatically be included when they are added.

```
a(CurrentForm()).diff(set('125'))
```